# Inefficient query or am I reaching the limits of Access?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have been taking an online class on relational databases and created an Access database (for the first time) to practice my SQL queries and solve a couple of work-related problems along the way. The database consists of three tables, with the primary table being used to record company wide sales summary information at the branch/store/menu item level (e.g. lowest level of detail) and with three periods of data the database is presently 1.3GB with that one table containing 4,262,421 records.

Everything has gone well until I attempted to run the following query:

```
SELECT P1.*, P13.[Price?] AS P13Price
FROM (SELECT * FROM PBASE WHERE Period = 13) AS P13, (SELECT * FROM PBASE WHERE Period = 1) AS P1
WHERE P1.Key = P13.Key and P1.[Price?]<>P13.[Price?];
```

To explain, the big table is PriceAccData and so I first ran a query (PBASE) that added a field to the PriceAccData that I can use as a key to compare price changes from one period to the next (combination of branch, store, menu item). Then I used subqueries to create a data set from the last period of 2013 (Period 13) and the first period of 2014 (Period 1)....from there I attempted to identify items that had changed in price from one period to the next in the Where clause.

Is there a more efficient way to write the query or to accomplish the comparison....it will work for one branch at a time, but takes a long time and locks up Access if I run it for more than one branch.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries are always known to be inefficient and are used as last resort. There's usually a way to JOIN tables for better efficiency. I suggest something in the line of :

```
SELECT ...... FROM PBASE P13 INNER JOIN PBASE P1 ON P13.KEY=P1.KEY
```

this will give you the data for the 2 periods then you can check for your equality criteria. Let me know if you need further help for that

Comment: Thank you for the tip Don, that did return the results much more promptly....but the problem I'm now having is that after the query has run and the results are on the screen I get the spinning blue circle every few seconds which locks up Access while it is spinning. Any idea why that would be happening or how to stop it? It is very frustrating to see that the query has completed and have my results on the screen, but not be able to use them.

Comment: Normally, you won't just select all the required rows (especially if it's so much) to display because this uses up RAM (memory). So if the rows are really much, i suspect that's what brings up the spinning blue circle. You can try to look at your CPU and RAM utilization for Access from Task Manager while this is happening

Comment: Thanks again for responding...the query properly returns over 200K records. What I found has helped is the following: First the relation PBase was originally a query..and so I changed PBase to export to a table in a new database. Once I had done that then I was working in a smaller overall database which I believe helped. The next step is that I created P1 and P13 as separate queries of PBase that I then joined as you described (turning one query into three separate queries). This combination of steps has the final query return results promptly and without the spinning blue circle.